# AI tool for troubleshooting in logs and dumps

Tags: artificial-intelligence

What I want is a AI tool that searches through large logs or dumps to troubleshoot problems. The AI tool should be able to identify problems by patterns (or other solution), to give the user proposals how the problem can be solved (or at least might be).

I can not finds any software that can do something like this, but it feels like there should exist some, because there's a lot of companies with large logs and dumps, and it seems unlikely that they troubleshooting manually. So if anyone can suggest software tools that match the description, or partially (so I can build upon it to get what I want), it would be great.

**Edit:**
To clarify a bit. There is no OS or cost requirements. I don´t know if it lies in the "big data"-area for my purpose (should run on a PC). The files are a couple of GB (1-3 GB in general) and the number of files are not so large that it would require a datacenter either. The logs are created by different parts of the system, and because they might change, any general type of log could be used. The rules will be built-in, and changed/added by some in the personal, and the result (troubleshooting solutions) would be provided to the support team. As Thomas in the comments below mentioned, it is a expert system I am looking for.

Comment: This is quite broad. What kind of logs? I have logs in my company, less than 100 of them. Quite unlikely that this is sufficient to build a big data query from that. Microsoft however, is analyzing crash dumps and assigns a "stack hash" to them. So there, the concept exists. Unfortunately you'll not get direct access to that data.

Comment: It's also unclear to me if the AI tool should have the rules built-in or you want a neuronal network and train it yourself. Do you have ans OS requirements or cost requirements? Are you a developer, and can you deal with big data languages like R? Other than the open issues, I like the idea in general. If you edit the question, drop me an @ comment so that I can upvote if all open points are clarified.

Comment: @Thomas : Hope it's more clear now. I am a developer, and used R a little bit before. Any programming language are welcome.

Comment: Ok, now the description sounds much less like a neuronal network and more like an [expert system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expert_system), which is a subset of AI. Would you agree?

Comment: @Thomas Yes, a expert system seems to fit my description. I will add that to the description